# Drupal - get user id in non-drupal script

Tags: php, session, drupal

im making an applicaiton (PHP), which will run on same server and same website as a Drupal installation. The think im trying to do is to get user id of user, who is currently logged in at Drupal (i never worked with Drupal before). I want just that id.

Does anyone know, where can i find that id (is it somewhere in the $_SESSION variable?)

Im using Drupal 6, PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update :**

Sorry, I thought I understood what you wanted, but after re-reading your subject line, I'm thinking you want something a little different. Are you wanting to make a php script like test.php in the Drupal folder and access the Drupal user ID (based on cookie/session/etc)? In order to do that, you'll need to "bootstrap" Drupal first. Here is a function I've created to bootstrap Drupal (7) for maintenance scripts I create.

There may be a "better" way to do it, but it's what works for me.

```
function bootstrapDrupal($cDomain)
{
    $cDir = getcwd();

    //SETS DRUPAL BASE DIR
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/www/dev');
    //DRUPAL FAILS TO LOAD SOME FILES IF NOT AT BASE
    chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);                                             

    //ATTEMPT TO DECIDE IF PHP IS RUNNING VIA CMDLINE
    if (isset($GLOBALS['PHP_SELF']))
    {
        //WHATEVER SITE YOUR SCRIPT IS FOR. HELPS SET DB.
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $cDomain;                       
        //SCRIPT ADDITIONALLY NEEDS TO BE SET FOR THE REDIRECT
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $GLOBALS['PHP_SELF'];
        //FORWARD SLASH IS IMPORTANT
        if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, 1) != '/')       
        {
            $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        }

        //NEEDED TO SUPRESS BOOTSTAP ACCESS ERRORS - ANY IP WILL WORK
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '192.168.0.1';

    }

    //LOADS DRUPAL BOOTSTRAP CODE
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';           
    //EXECUTES BOOTSTRAP
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);                        
    //LOADS DRUPAL COMMON FUNCTIONS
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/common.inc';              

    //BACK TO STARTING DIRECTORY
    chdir($cDir);                                                   
}
```

**Original Answer :**

In Drupal you can access the User ID via :

```
$GLOBALS['user']->uid
```

or

```
global $user;
$user->uid
```

Comment: If the user ID is all that is needed, you can probably get away with bootstrapping with DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION instead of FULL (saves some time).